# Reset the time in angularJs using ng-Model.(example 25/05/2016 12:12:52 into 25/05/2016 00:00:00)

Tags: angularjs

How to reset the time in angularJs.(example 25/05/2016 12:12:52 into 25/05/2016 00:00:00)

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
new Date(YOUR_DATE_OBJECT.getFullYear(), YOUR_DATE_OBJECT.getMonth(), YOUR_DATE_OBJECT.getDate()).setHours(0,0,0,0)
```